# How to replace all "False" values in any columns by values from other columns with the same names if that values are not False

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, drop

for example:

```
import pandas as pd


dc1 = {
    'n':[1, 2, 3, 4],
    'a':[0, 2, 0.0, 4],
    'b':[0,'', False, 5],
    }

dc2 = {
    'n':[1, 2, 3, 4],
    'a':[1, 0, 3, 0.0],
    'b':[6, 5, 8, 9],
    }
```

Merge on **'n'** column. Is it possible values in **'a'(and 'b')** column in **df1** is replaced by values of **'a'** (and 'b') column in **df2** if value of **'a'(and 'b')** in **df1** is **False** (or some values that we can manually set **[False, 0, 0.0, 'Nan', None, '','Null']**), and then drop column with suffix _drop?

In result (dict for example) must be that:

```
dc_result = {
    'n':[1, 2, 3, 4],
    'a':[1, 2, 3, 4],
    'b':[6, 5, 8, 5],
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using [DataFrame.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to convert all "False" values into NaN, then using [DataFrame.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill those NaN values with the other dataframe?

Comment: `df1.set_index('n').combine_first(df2.set_index('n')).reset_index()` but you'd need real NaNs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isin` to get the indexes where a cell in `a` or `b` contains an element from a manual list: `[False, 0, 0.0, 'Nan', None, '','Null']` and use `np.where` to replace those elements:

```
replace_list = [False, 0, 0.0, 'Nan', None, '','Null']
df1[['a', 'b']] = ( np.where(df1[['a', 'b']].isin(replace_list), df2[['a', 'b']], 
                                                   df1[['a', 'b']]).astype(int) )
```